# Is there a shorthand way to write nested properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With ES6 there's a shorthand way to write top level properties for example.

```
randomFunction({
    data: data
});

randomFunction({
    data // no need for :data
});
```

Is there a way to have something like this?

```
randomFunction({
    data: {
        a: data.a
    }
});
randomFunction({
    data.a
});
```

Comment: I'll edit the question. I was meaning how in ES6 you can just pass in data vs `data: data`. I was wondering if there's a shorthand version for that.

Comment: You are defining a new object `data`. What is expected result?

Comment: Check the edit. That should make a lot more sense.

Comment: Is `x` expected to be an object, or the value of `data.a`? It is not clear what expected input and result within function are.

Comment: so, you want to know if you can write `randomFunction({data.a});` instead of `randomFunction({a:data.a});` ? no, you can't

Comment: @JaromandaX other than using deconstructing inside of randomFunction is the no other way current implemented? I'm fine with either babel or ES6 - ES8.

Comment: @AlexisTyler - put your code in babel repl - see how it doesn't like it - conclusion: it's not valid syntax

Comment: @JaromandaX Well clearly they know that syntax doesn't work, hence the phrase 'something *like* this'

Comment: @Rob there's also the fact that ES6, ES7, ES8 and babel with stage-2, etc enabled all have different little features. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @Rob - sure, but `randomFunction({a:data.a});` is valid ... the only POSSIBLE way to "shorten" that would presumably be `randomFunction({data.a});` - which is invalid ... so, I can't see any other **SHORTHAND** - anything other than the original code would be LONGER

Comment: Why replicating the same structure in the argument, can't you just invoke the function with `randomFunction({data})`? What's the need of doing { `data: { a: data.a } }`? Just deep clone the object if you need a new copy

Comment: I don't want to pass in the other field on data.

Comment: `data` is an identifier, not a property of the original object `const data = {a: 'red', b: 'blue'};`. The Question mentions "shorthand", though you are apparently expecting a new object which has `data` as a property.

Comment: Oh I see, I'd use something like lodash's [`pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) to create a new object then.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti from the looks of it pick does close to what I want but requires me to use lodash which I was hoping to avoid as I was expecting one of the new versions of js to have this built in.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in, but you could write your own function, here's a basic implementation: `const pick = (o, ...props) => Object.assign({}, ...props.map(prop => ({[prop]: o[prop]})));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorthand object literal syntax assumes that the property name is precisely equivalent to the name of a variable in-scope.

```
{a} // {a: a}
```

So there's no way to do exactly what you propose, since `data.a` is not a variable. The only alternative would be

```
const {a} = data;
{a}
```

More generally, you are looking for the ability to deconstruct/pick into an object, as in

```
randomFunc(data PICK a)
```

but no such feature exist, or is planned, although various proposals have been made; here's one, called "extended dot notation", which the powers that be on TC39 have shown absolutely no interest in:

```
randomFunc(data.{a})
```

It has also been discussed to allow precisely the syntax you propose:

```
{ data.a } // {a: data.a}
```

but this has also gotten no traction whatsoever, and in any case is not very DRY if you are interested in more than one property:

```
{ data.a, data.b } // requires repeating "data"
```